# MultiDataTrigger does not change IsReadOnly property of TextBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, multidatatrigger

I am using `MultiDataTrigger` in multi-line `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                    FlowDirection="RightToLeft" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    Text="{Binding ArabicDescription}" IsReadOnly="True">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=EnableNewEntry}" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=AllowArabic}" Value="True" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

When `EnableNewEntry` and `AllowArabic` become true, the `TextBox` is supposed to become Read-only. For just testing, I changed background color as well. Problem is `IsReadOnly` does not change where as `Background` duly changes.

I also tried following setter, but it does not work either:

```
<Setter Property="TextBox.IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Ritesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not expicitly set IsReadolny to True
Use the MultiDataTrigger you already have to set it to false and another one to set it to true whenever you want it but DO NOT SET IT at TextBox properties

Comment: I did not set IsReadOnly property to True originally. Following your suggestion, I defined multiple MultiDataTrigger (one with **true** and one with **false**), and it works. But can't it work with single MultiDataTrigger?

Comment: I was talking about the IsReadOnly="True" you placed in your Textbox attributes just before you define TextBox.Style. Once you remove this it can work with just one MultidataTrigger.